# Is the device token changes if Uninstall/reinstall App for same device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

Im getting multiple notifications for same app..

if It changes how to delete the old one form our server..

Here is my observation in iOS 9 device

1.There are two fields in DB APPId and Device token If I unstalled the app and installed it again in the same device the device token changes..

2.I tested another app in the same device The Device Token is different even the same device

Im getting 3 notifications to the same device Even If I deleted the first device token one from my DB…. I didn’t understand still whiz the reason for multiple notifications..

What might be the possible reasons ?

Comment: @Krishna Can you tell me your question info in brief? so i provide you exact solution for it.

Comment: @PavanGandhi Let's say Installed app for the first time(device token inserted in our database). if user uninstalled the app, and installed again .. Is the device token changes ? if  its changes how to delete old one from my DB ?

Comment: just Follow solution which i provide you if faced any problem then inform me

Comment: Are you login multiple accounts from same device ?

Comment: @technerd No, Im asking about Uninstalling/Reinstall case

Answer (score 4):

The `Device token` is change in the following conditions.

- If the user restores backup data to a new device.
- Reinstalls the App

So my suggestion is to update the server with the new token.

When every time app is launch in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` you have to call api which update the device token if changes.

In your DB create two more fields as `device token` and `APPId` so, update `device token` with respect to `APPId`.

Get `APPId` or unique device id from device keychain and send it to your server with `device token` so, at server update `device token`  with respect to `APPId`.

`keychain` value will never change in the above following conditions.

For getting Keychain value follow  [Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972074/8023444)

```
// MARK: - Push Notification Delegate Methods.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        //send this device token to server

        let token = String(data: deviceToken.base64EncodedData(), encoding: .utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))

        //Save device to UserDefaults
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(token, forKey: "DeviceToken")
        defaults.synchronize()

        print("token is ---\(token)")

        print("AppId ----\(getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString)")

        //Send token value and AppId to server

    }

     var getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString : String {

        let appname =  Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String

        var strApplicationUUID: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: appname)
        if strApplicationUUID == nil {
            strApplicationUUID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
            _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(strApplicationUUID!, forKey: appname)
        }

        return strApplicationUUID!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new web service for logout session and call this service when you logout and this service told your backend developer to remove your device token from database.

Comment: Instead of removing a device token from server, we can turn off push inside the app it self (at the time of logout).

Comment: @Akshay Patel It's Ok when login/Logout. i need in case of uninstalled and reinstalled the app once again ?

Comment: when user install the app and login after the installation, user uninstalled the app after that user again go to install the app. In that case device token remain same or changed.

Answer (score 0):

@Krishna : Device Token remains Same as You installed the app on first time and uninstalled and once again you installed this app on same device.

if you use second time new Device then device token will be different.

Note : Just inform backend developer to Do below thing :

1. The ApI which you use for inserting device token in database, in that he need to check if device token is diff and update it new one. otherwise simply use whatever pass with web service.

Its work fine.

Comment: first you need to check whether device token of users device is exist or not.

if not present then add device token of that users.
if present then get details and update its device token

Comment: we are not checking with UserId(even though user not logged in  we need devicetoken  of that device).  I was just checked in my DB 
There are two fields in DB APPId and Device token If I unstalled the app and if installed again in the same device the device token changes..

Comment: Im getting 3 notifications to the same device Even If I deleted the first device token one from my DB…. I didn’t understand still whiz the reason for multiple notifications..

Answer (score 0):

[iOS9 and later](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1), Device Token might change each time app is re installed. So the best way is to store(update or insert to the DB) the Device token on each launch.